# How to Set Boundary Limits instead of Threshold for Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to manipulate an image on Matlab for it to display in a binary format based off of color intensities of a given range instead of using "levels" as a threshold.

Is there something like this built in?

Comment: you mean something like `img > thresh1 AND img < thresh2`?

Comment: what do you think a color intensity is and how do you differenciate it against a "level"